# Querying MongoDb with a date range using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a Rust program that is inserting the record in Mongo database. Rust is using local time (EST). Mongo database has the field defined as Bson Date. When I check the field in CompassDB, the date field is shown as `datetime: 2023-05-21T10:37:21.270+00:00`. ([Link](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-date/) to documentation)

I am facing issue while querying a Mongo database from a NestJs application using mongoose. The query has a date range, and MongoDB is returning zero records during find operation.

I have created the schema as following -

```
@Schema({ collection: 'PerformanceData' })
export class Perf{
    @Prop()
    datetime: Date;
    
    @Prop()
    hostname: string;

    @Prop()
    query: string;

    @Prop()
    value: number;
}
```

I have followed the steps as mentioned [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb) and [here](https://dev.to/carlomigueldy/building-a-restful-api-with-nestjs-and-mongodb-mongoose-2165)

The code that is querying the data from Mongo DB is -

```
async getPerfDataForServer(serverName: string, startTime: number, endTime: number): Promise<Perf[]>{
    console.log("Into getPerfData", serverName, startTime, endTime);
    const startDateTime = new Date(startTime);
    console.log("The datetime is", startDateTime,startDateTime.toLocaleDateString(),startDateTime.toLocaleTimeString())
    const endDateTime = new Date(endTime);
    console.log("The end datetime is", endDateTime,endDateTime.toLocaleDateString(),endDateTime.toLocaleTimeString())
    const query = {hostname: serverName, datetime: {$gte: startDateTime, $lte: endDateTime}}
    console.log("The query is", query)
    const perfData = await this.perfModel.find(query).exec();
    if (!perfData || perfData.length == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    return perfData;
}
```

When I console log the query, I get the following entry -

```
The query is {
  hostname: 'FQDN',
  datetime: {
    '$gte': 2023-05-21T14:35:00.000Z,
    '$lte': 2023-05-21T14:38:00.000Z
  }
}
```

As per console log the datetime is in UTC. If Mongo is using the same date `2023-05-21T14:35:00.000Z` then there will be no record to return. I have checked the Locale function. I tried `toLocaleString("en-us")`, it is showing the query as, but it is still returning zero records. I also tried by sending the time which is 4 hours behind (basically 06:35:21) and then it returned the records.

```
{
  hostname: 'FQDN',
  datetime: {
    '$gte': '5/21/2023, 10:35:00 AM',
    '$lte': '5/21/2023, 10:38:00 AM'
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the type of the $gte and $lte values seemingly different between those two outputs? The latter looks like a string?

Comment: I'm separately confused about the values. You said the information in the database is `10:37:21.270` UTC. So why are you querying a timeframe 4 hours later?

Comment: I am not. From ui, I am sending epoch (ms), which is being converted to Date object. The date object converts it into UTC and hence 4 hours difference.